# Wireless on Ubuntu - connects but websites do not load

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking

I have Ubuntu 10.10, and I am able to detect my wi-fi connection and I am able to connect to it using the correct credentials. However, after connecting, when I visit any website, the website does not load just as if there is no internet connection. I am perplexed. Please help.

Edit: I must add that with the same laptop, I am able to connect it at work (on ubuntu), and with windows XP, both work and home.

Comment: Do you have an IP address?  To find out open a command prompt (terminal window) and type `ifconfig`

Comment: When I did that, I received 127.0.0.1 as inet addr in one section called "lo", and 192.168.1.103 in another section named "wlan0".

Answer (score 1):

Ok now you should start windows and write down infos about its ip configuration.

You can do this starting xp then clicking on start and writing in execute field:

cmd

and then press enter.

There you get a black window and type in it:

ipconfig /all

Copy and paste that info here :)

If you feel like a ubuntu-only solution I think you can have wrong dns (for your home configuration).
In that case use 208.67.222.222 which is opendns: reliable, free, clean and available (generally) both from home and office.

In any case take note of current config so you can switch back if you have troubles

Comment: (I had initially downvoted his answer because I don't like assuming that someone will have windows.  Than I noticed the OP mentions having windows, so I removed my downvote)

Comment: Argh! It's still there! That's cruel! :D

Comment: Yeah, I saw that.  I'm not sure if that's from me or from someone else....

Comment: I rectified it with a +1. I was borderline but righting an injustice swayed me.

Comment: No problem at all :)

I need a little points to enable double clicking so I try my best :)

Answer (score 0):

The one called "lo" will always exist.  127.0.0.1 is a special IP that means "myself"   127.0.0.1 always points to the computer that is running the command in question

The other one is your IP address, which is good.  It confirms that you have successfully connected to your router.   Next up, can you `ping` anything?

Try doing `ping www.google.com` or `ping superuser.com` and see if you get results back.  NOTE: this program will run until you kill it.  Kill it by typing `ctrl-c`  Once you kill it, it will display a summary.  It will most likely say one of two things:  either `0% packet loss` or `100% packet loss`.

Post the last 3 lines of output from ping in a comment here.

Comment: When I do "ping www.google.com" - I get a "ping: unknown host www.google.com". Same for other websites.

Comment: What are you using for DNS?

Comment: Also, can you ping directly to an IP address?  `ping 209.85.225.99` ?